# How to get Unicode of smiley

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, sqlite

I'm working on a iPhone chat app and I'm having problem when I'm saving the smilies which wrapped with the text into Sqlite3 database and retrive them back.

Or I'm wondering is there anyway to get Unicode of a smiley typed from the iPhones default keyboard (emoji type).

Comment: [**Here**](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/where-can-i-find-an-explained-list-of-emoji-emoticons-used-in-ios) is an adequate post which describes how to get and map the unicode of emoji type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can find the unicode characters for the emoj or smiley on [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) & [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-461.13/icuSources/data/translit/Any_SoftbankSMS.txt)

for setting the smiley on the label for example

```
self.label.text= @"\U0001F604";
```

if you need to convert unicode to emoj or vise versa

**convert Emoji to unicode**

```
  NSData *data = [strEmo dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]; 
  NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**convert unicode to Emoji**

```
NSData *data = [strEmo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, Its working great!! thanks Buddy!!! :-) may this will appear as smiley lol!!!